# The Ontology for State Machines / other tools for designing state machines

Tags: c#, .net, state-machine, ontology, owl

I have a question regarding state machines. Can Ontology be used for state machines. I have a real-time application so performance is an issue. How will be its performance. And what are the alternatives for designing an state machine. Is there any tool specific for creating state machine for .Net. I had a look at the following link but do not know how stable it is.

http://people.cs.aau.dk/~dolog/fsm/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Ontology is more of an abstract concept that has some issues with respect to what you are trying to accomplish.  Ontology has a philosophical part to it that makes opinion and human ideologies effect the outcome.

State Machines are more black and white, where Ontology has a lot of gray areas.

But if you are looking for some good state machines code that is stable, I would recommend you should check out StateProto and QHSM.  Open source project is here: http://code.google.com/p/gqhsm/

If performance of the c# code becomes and issue, you can have Mono (C# compiler) compile to native mode.